# Output K-means association rules

Tags: spss-modeler

Is there a way to make SPSS Modeler output the association rules when performing a clustering analysis like K-means? I'd like to have the set of rules that associate any observation to a certain cluster (like Var1<0 and Var2 = 1 then cluster = A and so on) so that I'm able to use it regardless of SPSS.
I looked for that in SPSS online tutorial but no success. I know that it outputs the rules for decision tree nodes, so it seemed to me just natural that it would work the same for K-means and etc. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a derive node with that logic ( if Var1<0 and Var2 = 1 then cluster = 1 else 0 endif ) and then use that new variable as input in the K-Means Model Node. I use some similar variables in the Anomaly node and works fine for me. Just remember to use a Type node in front of K-Means node and set that variable as input.

Hope to have been helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Those are two different types of analysis and I'd kindly ask: what do you really want to achieve?
Clustering means that you group observations.
Association rules (recommendation engine) would suit you if your observations have made multiple activities or choices and you want to see the next most likely choice.
But what you described looks more like a classification task to me, e.g. different approach, because you described a rule set, and that is exactly what certain classification models return.
http://share.opsy.st/56e7090e92b6c-MathWorks_Figure+1_Machine+Learning+Types.jpg